# Typescript: How can I examine my variable type easier and faster when I'm not directly specifying it in a variable?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Please see this minimum **typescript** example code and my **VSCode screenshot**:

```
function greeting(name: string) {
  return `Hello ${name}`
}

// version 1
const myGreeting = greeting('Joseph')
console.log(myGreeting)

// version 2
console.log(greeting('Joseph'))
```

[image]
[image]

In **version 1**, VSCode directly shows me the type that `greeting('Joseph')` returned by easily hover that assigned variable.

But in **version 2**, although I can still tell that the return type is `string` according to what VSCode showed me by hovering the function, it will become a little bit harder to tell when my function grows.

Is it possible when I write **version 2** code but I can get **version 1** VSCode result when hovering it?

Comment: are you looking for typeof operator?

Comment: const myGreeting = greeting('Joseph');

console.log ( typeof myGreeting);
console.log ( typeof greeting('Joseph'));
function greeting(name) {
return 'Hello '+ name;
}

Comment: No, I'm not looking for `typeof`'s result, I'm looking for `typescript`'s type result, which may contain various type(union type or object literal type, etc...)